# localhost icmp packet found in capture file: why?

Tags: ip, localhost, packet-capture, tcpdump, icmp

Here's my `tcpdump` filter (`ip[8]` is the IP ttl field and `icmp[0]=11` corresponds to time-exceeded ICMP messages):

```
(ip and ip[8]=2 and src host $myIPAddress) or (icmp and dst host $myIPAddress and icmp[0]=11)
```

And here's what I found in the capture file:

```
>>> p.show()
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst       = 00:15:f2:e3:90:e9
  src       = 00:11:43:e5:48:10
  type      = 0x800
###[ IP ]###
     version   = 4L
     ihl       = 5L
     tos       = 0xc0
     len       = 56
     id        = 19126
     flags     = 
     frag      = 0L
     ttl       = 254
     proto     = icmp
     chksum    = 0xa697
     src       = 127.0.0.1
     dst       = 127.0.0.1
     \options   \
```

Why did I capture an **ICMP localhost** packet? What's the purpose of such packet anyway? And, most importantly, why didn't it get rejected by the above filter?

Comment: myIpAddress contains something different than 127.0.0.1, right?

Comment: Yes, it's not localhost.

Comment: A weird part is also that this packet has different src/dst mac addresses but in the ip layer we have the same IP. If you open the pcap file with wireshark you get the same result?

Comment: What happens if you run tcpdump with the same filter, and on the same network interface, and with the `-d` flag?  It will print the code generated for the filter expression, so that we can see exactly what it's checking for, and therefore determine why a packet with 127.0.0.1 in the source and destination IP address field would match the filter.

Answer (score 0):

What is "$myIpAddress"? Was it literally an IPv4 address? If it was actually anything resembling an FQDN or hostname, then the man page explains what happens:

http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html

```
 host host
 (stuff removed)
 If host is a name with multiple IP addresses, each address will be checked for a match.
```

I'm not sure what happens if it was, probably the IP is mapped to the MAC address?

I like Guy's suggestion about using -d.

Comment: it was the IP address of the machine where I ran my script. As for the rest, it was one year ago. I don't remember :)